# windows 7 randomly shuts down. where do I find related log? so that i can identify the error

Tags: windows-7, logging, windows-7-restore

during the normal use, windows 7 shuts down. sometimes it happened when I start google chrome and few times during system update.

after it shuts down, I turn it back on and I get to the screen, where windows asks me if I'd like a safe or normal start. the shutdown happens regardless if i'm on a battery or cord

is there a log that can tell me where the error is? it can help me to further identify the solution.

my setup:
I run windows 7 on thinkpad x201 tablet. i have upgraded hard drive that worked fine for the last 6 months. the system is dual boot with ubuntu. I have installed some software recently, may be that can be the problem but sophos anti-virus cannot find anything. updates are all up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows logs are available in the "[Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer)":

> Event Viewer is an advanced tool that displays detailed information
>   about significant events on your computer. It can be helpful when
>   troubleshooting problems and errors with Windows and other programs.
>
> Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button, clicking Control
>   Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, clicking Administrative Tools,
>   and then double-clicking Event Viewer.‌  If you are prompted for an
>   administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>   confirmation.
>
> Note
>
> Here's another way to open Event Viewer: Click the Start button . In
>   the Search box, type Event Viewer, and then, in the list of results,
>   double-click Event Viewer.

Start under "Windows Logs", and look in "System" (for possible error events related to the hardware), and "Application" for software errors.  Look around the time-frame in which the shutdowns happen.

Aside form the logs, as others have mentioned, it sounds like it may be overheating, which may not be logged.  Ensure your intake and exhaust vents, heat-sink and fan are free of dust and debris, and that your system fan spins and spins (under it's own power) at power-on.

Comment: i've used it but i couldn't understand what logs to look at.

Comment: I'll update my answer a bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may check for a memory dump and analyze it with a program called [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed).

The memory dump will usually be in one of 2 places.
%systemroot%\memory.dmp
or more commonly for desktops
%systemroot%\minidump\*

You can locate the location of your memory dumps for sure under Startup and Recovery in the Advanced System Properties tab of the system properties.

Not all crashes create these but it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can cause a random full shutdown would be overheating, either the CPU or graphics cards are the usual culprits in notebook type computers and if you changed to a higher power drive then that may contribute too.

I would have a look at the [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) as it is quite good for seeing various component temperatures in most machines.