# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB2528583) won't install

Tags: windows-update, sql-server-2008-r2

When I tried to update using Windows Update, it just "hangs" at the "Installing" step.

When I downloaded the patch and ran it myself, a console screen just pops up and disappears, and does nothing.

EDIT:

I just installed it, but after checking for updates, it's still on the list. When I tried reinstalling it, I get error 84C4000B. I deleted the files in the downloaded install folder, rebooted my PC and tried again. It's now stuck again.

I'm now trying another patch. This time its the Security Update for SQL Server 2008 R2 (KB2494088), and in my logs, it's been stuck in "Updates to install = 1", just like it did for SP1.

```
2011-12-03  07:03:59:010     536    14cc    Agent     *   Title = Security Update for SQL Server 2008 R2 (KB2494088)
2011-12-03  07:03:59:010     536    14cc    Agent     *   UpdateId = {2212D902-7C3B-408E-96A3-ECE4D00BFAE6}.100
2011-12-03  07:03:59:010     536    14cc    Agent     *     Bundles 1 updates:
2011-12-03  07:03:59:010     536    14cc    Agent     *       {13017DB1-F976-46E7-B465-8BA20E93DEE0}.100
2011-12-03  07:03:59:029     536    1114    AU  Getting featured update notifications.  fIncludeDismissed = true
2011-12-03  07:03:59:029     536    1114    AU  No featured updates available.
2011-12-03  07:04:09:543     536    14cc    DnldMgr Preparing update for install, updateId = {13017DB1-F976-46E7-B465-8BA20E93DEE0}.100.
2011-12-03  07:04:10:447    5100    398 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.5.7601.17514, tz: +1100)  ===========
2011-12-03  07:04:10:447    5100    398 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2011-12-03  07:04:10:448    5100    398 Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\system32\wuaueng.dll
2011-12-03  07:04:10:447    5100    398 Handler :::::::::::::
2011-12-03  07:04:10:448    5100    398 Handler :: START ::  Handler: Command Line Install
2011-12-03  07:04:10:448    5100    398 Handler :::::::::
2011-12-03  07:04:10:448    5100    398 Handler   : Updates to install = 1
```

Comment: What do the [Windows Update Logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093) report? Anything in the [Event Logs](http://superuser.com/a/363155/23133)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602. This could be one of many things. That wizard will assist you with some possible solutions. In order to troubleshoot this type of issue we would need the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only install the patches on SQL Server 2008 R2. Be careful, if it's not an SQL Server 2008 R2, you can't update the patches.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled SQL 2008 R2 and reinstalled with default settings (as customizing them resulted in other problems). I was able to update it to SP1 without any more issues.